# should I use Convert class?

Tags: c#, string, long-integer

For instance, in the following scenario

```
Convert.Int64(string somstring)
```

or

```
long.Parse(string somstring);
```

appear to be doing same kind of work. Which one is a better practice ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the source, `Convert.ToInt64(string)` simply calls `long.Parse`, but checks that the string isn't `null` first.

I would recommend callings `long.Parse` because it makes the intent (string parsing) clearer.

I recommend using the `Convert` class if the type that you're converting *from* might change.  (Or if you're converting from `object`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer +1. Could you please tell me where to find the c# source for some methods?

Comment: Reflector (http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) or the .Net Reference Source (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness to the other answers, don't forget about [long.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2x2b1h.aspx) which is generally safer if you are unsure of the input string format.

Answer (score 1):

`Convert.Int64` calls `long.Parse` internally, just does a null check before.  Here's the guts:

```
if (value == null)
{
    return 0L;
}
return long.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

If you need the null check, Convert.Int64 is safer that's all, otherwise no difference.

Comment: Beat me again by exactly one second ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Convert.Int64 actually calls long.Parse with the CultureInfo.CurrentCulture after first doing a null check on the string.  So as long as you know the string is not going to be null, you can save the step and call long.Parse